# How to override IdentityUserAppService in abp.io without duplicating endpoints?

Tags: c#, api, abp

I am using abp.io 4.4 (https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest) and want to write my own class to replace the IdentityUser AppService with an extended child, exactly as described in the [abp.io docs](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Customizing-Application-Modules-Overriding-Services#overriding-a-service-class).

When I do, all the original endpoints exist, even though I am trying to replace them with my new app service. How do I prevent the /api/identity endpoints from being generated?

I am not interested in just removing them from swagger, I am hoping to fix this at the sourfce if it is possible.

**Details of issue:**

Before coding anything beyond the default downloaded backend application, when swagger loads, I can see my list of endpoints as expected:

```
GET
​/api​/identity​/users​/{id}

PUT
​/api​/identity​/users​/{id}

DELETE
​/api​/identity​/users​/{id}

GET
​/api​/identity​/users

POST
​/api​/identity​/users

GET
​/api​/identity​/users​/{id}​/roles

PUT
​/api​/identity​/users​/{id}​/roles

GET
​/api​/identity​/users​/assignable-roles

GET
​/api​/identity​/users​/by-username​/{userName}

GET
​/api​/identity​/users​/by-email​/{email}
```

Once I add the new file UserAppService.cs as described in the docs:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension of the IdentityUserAppService.
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="IdentityUserAppService" />
    [Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]
    [ExposeServices(typeof(IIdentityUserAppService), typeof(IdentityUserAppService), typeof(UserAppService))]

    public class UserAppService : IdentityUserAppService
    {
        public UserAppService(
            IdentityUserManager userManager,
            IIdentityUserRepository userRepository,
            IIdentityRoleRepository roleRepository,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> identityOptions)
            : base(
                  userManager,
                  userRepository,
                  roleRepository,
                  identityOptions)
        {
        }

        public async Task<List<IdentityUserDto>> GetEntireCollectionAsync() => this.ObjectMapper.Map<List<Volo.Abp.Identity.IdentityUser>, List<IdentityUserDto>>(await this.UserRepository.GetListAsync());
    }
```

The swagger endpoints under User are now:

```
GET
​/api​/identity​/users​/{id}

PUT
​/api​/identity​/users​/{id}

DELETE
​/api​/identity​/users​/{id}

GET
​/api​/identity​/users

POST
​/api​/identity​/users

GET
​/api​/identity​/users​/{id}​/roles

PUT
​/api​/identity​/users​/{id}​/roles

GET
​/api​/identity​/users​/assignable-roles

GET
​/api​/identity​/users​/by-username​/{userName}

GET
​/api​/identity​/users​/by-email​/{email}

GET
​/api​/app​/user​/entire-collection

GET
​/api​/app​/user​/{id}

PUT
​/api​/app​/user​/{id}

DELETE
​/api​/app​/user​/{id}

GET
​/api​/app​/user

POST
​/api​/app​/user

GET
​/api​/app​/user​/{id}​/roles

PUT
​/api​/app​/user​/{id}​/roles

GET
​/api​/app​/user​/assignable-roles

POST
​/api​/app​/user​/find-by-username

POST
​/api​/app​/user​/find-by-email
```

Is there something wrong with my decorators, or is this expected behavior? Is there a way around it?

Comment: You are replacing IdentityUserAppService with your UserAppService service. So it's normal to see these endpoints on swagger because your UserAppService class inherit the IdentityUserAppService. If you don't want to see these endpoints you need to remove the IdentityUserAppService from your service collection and where it is used, you should use the class you created by injecting it.

Comment: I have used the line `context.Services.Replace(
    ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IIdentityUserAppService, UserAppService>()
);` but it doesn't make a difference. If you can provide any more details as an answer to the question I would be happy to accept it as best answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue with extending TenantAppService and tried multiple things but non of them worked, I ended up adding the attribute `[RemoteService(IsEnabled = false)]` for the extended AppService, and inherited from the class I want to extend 'for my case TenantAppService` and it worked.

[RemoteServiceAttributeDoc](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/API/Auto-API-Controllers#iremoteservice-interface)

`Code`:

```
[RemoteService(IsEnabled = false)]
[Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]
[ExposeServices(typeof(ITenantAppService), typeof(Volo.Abp.TenantManagement.TenantAppService))]
public class TenantAppService : Volo.Abp.TenantManagement.TenantAppService
{
    public TenantAppService(ITenantRepository tenantRepository, ITenantManager tenantManager, IDataSeeder dataSeeder, IDistributedEventBus distributedEventBus)
        : base(tenantRepository, tenantManager, dataSeeder, distributedEventBus)
    {
    }

    public override Task UpdateDefaultConnectionStringAsync(Guid id, string defaultConnectionString)
    {
        var str = defaultConnectionString;
        return base.UpdateDefaultConnectionStringAsync(id, defaultConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Before disabling remote service swagger:

```
Tenant


GET
/api/multi-tenancy/tenants/{id}


PUT
/api/multi-tenancy/tenants/{id}


DELETE
/api/multi-tenancy/tenants/{id}


GET
/api/multi-tenancy/tenants


POST
/api/multi-tenancy/tenants


GET
/api/multi-tenancy/tenants/{id}/default-connection-string


PUT
/api/multi-tenancy/tenants/{id}/default-connection-string


DELETE
/api/multi-tenancy/tenants/{id}/default-connection-string


GET
/api/app/tenant/{id}


PUT
/api/app/tenant/{id}


DELETE
/api/app/tenant/{id}


GET
/api/app/tenant


POST
/api/app/tenant


GET
/api/app/tenant/{id}/default-connection-string


PUT
/api/app/tenant/{id}/default-connection-string


DELETE
/api/app/tenant/{id}/default-connection-string
```

After disabling remote service swagger:

```
Tenant


GET
/api/multi-tenancy/tenants/{id}


PUT
/api/multi-tenancy/tenants/{id}


DELETE
/api/multi-tenancy/tenants/{id}


GET
/api/multi-tenancy/tenants


POST
/api/multi-tenancy/tenants


GET
/api/multi-tenancy/tenants/{id}/default-connection-string


PUT
/api/multi-tenancy/tenants/{id}/default-connection-string


DELETE
/api/multi-tenancy/tenants/{id}/default-connection-string
```